# Where is the right place to format RESTful Data?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, backbone.js

We are moving more and more to restful resources and have found it a little painful in the data formatting sense.  Dates for example come back in nasty full format and then require javascript or other code to do the formatting.

Relationships either aren't included or come back as id's unless you alter the as_json defaults to include the relationships.  My initial thought is to flatten the data by duplicating it on the table row but that doesn't work well for has_many.

Are there any articles or podcasts that cover the "right" way to approach this?

Answer (score 6):

Your presentation layer should format values for display - you should store your data in the most neutral format possible. The display of data is a concern of your UI - by formatting the data there you are allowing for multiple different UIs that could format the data different ways.

Comment: It's particularly worth bearing in mind that some Javascript frameworks can localise the displayed data (things like decimal separators, date formats, etc.) That kind of thing can be very messy if you try to make the server handle it.

Comment: And what about the relational records.  Categories or tags for example.  My initial thought is to duplicate the data and flatten it onto the same row for lightning fast lookups.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach for me was to move the format of rendered JSON data to the view layer, using the [rabl gem](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl).

It allows to write templates that describe how your JSON data is rendered, selecting which attributes and associations you want to include, along with nice other functions: partials, custom nodes, template inheritance, etc.